# Scraping php site with python for a beginner

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, web-scraping, request

I'm a complete newbie to scraping, and I'd like to get some data from here :
http://fse.vdkruijssen.eu/ferrylist.php

I'm using Python 2.7 as it is the only language I know something about.
I've tried and searched a lot, but there is a simple form to fill before accessing the data that I can't go through... No login required.

This is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://fse.vdkruijssen.eu/ferrylist.php'
params ={'selectplane':'Cessna 208 Caravan','submit':''}

response=requests.post(url, data=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
print soup
```

Any help would be highly appreciated... 
Thank you !

EDITED & SOLVED : thank you 宏杰李!

Comment: your code gives HTML with results - so now learn how to use `BeautifulSoup` to search data in HTML.

Comment: the code is fine, what's your question?

Comment: Please edit your question to add exactly what your problem is. Don't just ask it in the comment. That way you will get your answer faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params ={'selectplane':'Cessna 208 Caravan',
        'submit':''}
```

You missed a param:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. Now beautifulsoup is raising a looping error